# script does not execute

Tags: arch-linux, raspberry-pi, ntp, clock

I have rPi B+ running ArchLinux with kernel `Linux comp001 3.18.6-2-ARCH #1 PREEMPT Sun Feb 8 09:43:43 MST 2015 armv6l GNU/Linux` with Real Time Clock hardware [RTC Pi](https://www.abelectronics.co.uk/products/3/Raspberry-Pi/15/RTC-Pi). However, I would like to check if there is internet connection at boot time with running ntp client. If ntp client connects to ntp server and fetches clock, I do now want to sync clock with hardware. I want to use hw clock only when internet connection (ntp client check return code) is offline. I've built a service, which runs ok, but I do not know how to check if ntp client was launched without any problems. How do I chechk that? Ok, I have been working on following script with corrected spaces and still does not work:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ ?('modprobe -v rtc_ds1307') = 0 ]; then
    # rtc is connected and working, use it

    echo "RTC Hardware connected, getting time"

    systemctl disable ntpd.service
    systemctl stop ntpd.service

    echo "ds1307 0x68" > /sys/class/i2c-adapter/i2c-1/new_device
    hwclock -s
else
    # rtc is offline / not connected, get time via ntp

    echo "RTC Hardware disconnected/battery dead/offline, use NTP"

    systemctl enable ntpd.service
    systemctl start ntpd.service
fi
```

Why does exeuction of script fails in first 3rd line with:

```
./script_rtc.sh: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `'modprobe -v rtc_ds1307''
./script_rtc.sh: line 3: `if [?('modprobe -v rtc_ds1307')=0]; then'
```

Answer (score 0):

I've rewritten the if clause via:

```
#!/bin/sh

modprobe -v rtc_ds1307

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    # rtc is connected and working, use it

    echo "RTC Hardware connected, getting time"

    systemctl disable ntpd.service
    systemctl stop ntpd.service

    echo "ds1307 0x68" > /sys/class/i2c-adapter/i2c-1/new_device
    hwclock -s
else
    # rtc is offline / not connected, get time via ntp

    echo "RTC Hardware disconnected/battery dead/offline, use NTP"

    systemctl enable ntpd.service
    systemctl start ntpd.service
fi
```

and now it works ok!